# How to find specificity of a regex match?

Tags: regex, url, routes, controller

I'm thinking about a routing system. Imagine I have the two following regexes

- `pathpart1/pathpart2`  => specific match that routes to controller1
- `.*` => catch-all that routes to controller2

And I let them match on a URL, e.g. 'pathpart1/pathpart2'.

They both match, but I would want to give prevalence to the specific match of the first regex. Is there a way to see that the first regex is *very specific* (so I want to to go with that match) and the second is completely not specific (so a match is basically a catch all last resort)...?

I do not know upfront which routes are registered with the router, so I can't loop over them in order of specificity (i.e. specific first, and the catch-all last if all others don't match).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rephrased, you're looking for a way to determine the **cardinality** of the range of a regular expression. This is no trivial task. For example, consider the most obvious complication: when the quantifiers `*` and `+` are involved, clearly the cardinality is ∞ in either case. But also to our intuition, some infinities [seem "greater" than others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Cantor), so we feel as if we should be able to order various regular expressions containing such infinite quantifiers.

I think you'll have to either (1) think about an alternate setup that *doesn't* require an ordering of regular expressions by specificity, or (2) consider a crude approximation, *e.g.* just two "classes" of regular expressions: those with one or more infinite quantifiers (unescaped `*` or `+` not inside square brackets), and those without.

Not to say there is no hope! Try posting this question at [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com), too.

Comment: Thanks, that was a great answer: I can read that you put thought into it..! :-) I'll make a simple estimation for now (the amount of quantifiers divided by the total amount of characters, and more weight on quantifiers at the beginning of the URL) and will ask the question on http://cs.stackexchange.com/ as well..!